# Flutter - How to add(create) a nested collection first time and then add fields(update the collection) next time in Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In this method I create a new collection("workouts") the first time a set(exercise set) is saved. A workout will have multiple exercises. So how do I add the next exercises to the same workout?

```
_saveExerciseSetForUser() {
if (currentUser != null) {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(currentUser!.uid)
      .collection("workouts")
      .doc()
      .collection("exercises")
      .doc(exerciseId)
      .collection("sets")
      .doc()
      .set({
    
    "setNo.": setCount,
    "weight": weightController.text,
    "reps": repsController.text,
    "toFailure": false
  }).then((value) => {
    
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add new exercises to existing workouts, you'll need to keep track of the doc or it's ID for your workout. Once you have the workout ID, you will know the path that you can add the new exercise to. `users/$userId/workouts/$workoutId/exercises/$exerciseId/sets`

```dart
Future<void> _saveExerciseSetForUser([String? workoutId]) async {
  if (currentUser == null) {
    return;
  }

  final data = {
    "setNo.": setCount,
    "weight": weightController.text,
    "reps": repsController.text,
    "toFailure": false,
  };

  final workoutDoc = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(currentUser!.uid)
    .collection("workouts")
    // if workoutId is null, this will create a new workout
    .doc(workoutId);

  // save doc id somewhere
  final workoutDocId = workoutDoc.id;

  await workoutDoc.collection("exercises")
    .doc(exerciseId)
    .collection("sets")
    .doc()
    .set(data);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "// save doc id somewhere" ? Also, why is workoutId passed as a parameter, where will it come from when it hasn't been generated yet?!

Comment: You'll need to keep track of the id if you are going to be saving more exercises to that work out. So you'll need to save (cache) it to the device so that you can reference it again

Comment: Cache it where, Saved Preferences?

Comment: hive, saved preferences, flutter cache manager. All of them work 

Comment: One last thing, here I set data, that is the first set. To add consecutive sets, I'll have to update the exercise document?

Comment: If you would like to update the exercise, then you can update it. If you would like to add a new exercise, you can create a new doc. Its up to you how you would like to structure your DB 

Comment: If this answer solved your question, don't forget to mark it as the answer 